# Articles before almost-abstract kind of nouns

Tags: articles

Should we use articles before nouns that are not fully generalized?

For example: "*the* birds of America" or "birds of America"?

We are considering not all birds, but all *American* birds. 
So what is the truth? "American birds" or "*the* American birds"?

Comment: This totally depends on what you want from the phrase to present. Am I right? Language is far wider than you and me can imagine! I can give you examples where both are correct.

Comment: I think that constructing some complete sentences as examples would be helpful. Maybe your confusion is not about when to use articles but about how adding an adjective affects how you understand the noun.

Answer (score 1):

They have no nationality, so we do not call them "American birds". They are "birds of America".

We could entitle a book *Birds of America* but when speaking of those birds as a group, we would use the definite article:

**The birds of America include seed-eaters, insect-eaters, raptors, and scavengers.**

But if we were speaking of an ornithological area of study, we might say:

**"Birds of America" would be too broad a subject for a PhD dissertation. You will have to find a narrower topic.**